# Array value needs to Text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a Array like

```
text=['2','2<sup>2</sup>','3<sup>10</sup>'.......];
```

I want result like this

```
text=['2','22','310'......];
```

How can i get This using javascript

```
var optionTxt = (xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('Option')[i].textContent ? xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('Option')[i].textContent : xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('Option')[i].text);
        optionList[i] = $.trim(optionTxt);
```

Comment: Have you considered using regex-based replacement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a [`.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) operation for that and replace any non-digit with nothing using [`.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace):

```
text.map(function(item) {
    return item.replace(/\D/g, '');
});
```

Since you're using jQuery you might also use their [`.map`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/) instead to fully benefit from cross (old) browser compatibility:

```
$.map(text, function(item) {
    return item.replace(/\D/g, '');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`.map()`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/) and [`.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace). Try this:

```
var text=['2','2<sup>2</sup>','3<sup>10</sup>'];
text = $.map(text,function(i){
    return i.replace( /[^\d.]/g,'');
});
console.log(text);
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/kunknown/b9NZ9/)**

Answer (score 0):

Try jQuery html parsing:

```
var text = ['2', '2<sup>2</sup>', '3<sup>10</sup>'];
var out = [];
jQuery.each(text, function (si, str) {
    var concat = '';
    jQuery.each(jQuery.parseHTML(str), function (ei, el) {
        concat = concat + el.textContent;
    });
    out.push(concat);
});
```

check out this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9cV7M/